# May be or will be?

Tags: grammar

> She may be/will be present at the time of her brother's marriage next month.

Which one is correct, or what's difference between two.

Comment: A quick google search establishes that: "The most obvious difference between maybe and may be is that maybe is an adverb, which means that it's modifying a verb/adjective/another adverb, and it means “perhaps” or “potentially”. May be is a verb phrase that implies that something is possible."

Comment: This is incredibly easy to answer with a google search.  If you search for "the difference between may be and will be" you will very quickly find your answer.  If a google search does not answer your question, then please update your question to include what research you did and why it did not answer your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think there is right or wrong when using these two phrases, the only question is when you use it, if you're sure she will present, then `will be` it is, if you're not sure, then `may be`.

Comment: Hello, Ayon. This question is not at all suitable for ELU. Giving an _answer_ sends the wrong message to the user base.

Comment: -1 no reference; full of comma splices; opinion ("I don't think") rather than fact; use of `backtick` formatting.